# taxi from gare du nord, Paris to avenue lamotte-piquet?

Tags: paris, taxis, train-stations

How much is a taxi from gare du nord, Paris to avenue lamotte-piquet

Comment: Why not the underground ?

Comment: You can get a quote on https://www.g7.fr/en/ though as pointed out by dotixx, the price will vary based on day and time, as they have an influence on traffic (and hence duration, which is one of the components of the cost) and the cost per km or hour.

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to tell because it would depend on the current traffic and at what time you do this ride (at night, prices go up...).
But Uber quotes this trip from 14 to 20€. I believe taxis would be around the same price ;)